# 固定値配列をテーブルとして扱う方法

Tags: mysql

例えば
f(x) = x * x  (x = 1..10)
の表を作りたいときに 1...10 の部分をどうやって作ればいいんでしょうか

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (
  x bigint(20)
);

INSERT x VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

SELECT x, x * x FROM x
```

こんな感じでテーブルを作るしかないんでしょうか

```
SELECT x, x * x FROM 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
```

みたいな書き方はできませんか？

補足：
MySQL 5.7 です

Comment: MySQL では[こんな感じ](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/121619/0)にするしかないでしょうね……

Comment: コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 8.0 だとこんな風に書けたりします。

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 1 AS xx UNION ALL SELECT x+1, (x+1)*(x+1) FROM t WHERE x<10
)
SELECT * FROM t;
+------+------+
| x    | xx   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    3 |    9 |
|    4 |   16 |
|    5 |   25 |
|    6 |   36 |
|    7 |   49 |
|    8 |   64 |
|    9 |   81 |
|   10 |  100 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: 素敵ですね。ただうちは 5.7 なので残念ながら使えないです…　バージョン書き忘れててすみません